# syntax error while using __int8 in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, dll

I have a header file which has function definitions for some of the APIs of a device to which I'm trying to communicate. I created a c++ project in eclipse juno and copied the header files into that project. When I open the header file I see a strange syntax error. The header file goes like this:

```
#ifndef AnaGate_h
#define AnaGate_h

// platform-independent fixed-size integer types
#ifdef WIN32
typedef signed __int8      AnaInt8;
typedef signed __int16     AnaInt16;
typedef signed __int32     AnaInt32;
typedef signed __int64     AnaInt64;

typedef unsigned __int8    AnaUInt8;
typedef unsigned __int16   AnaUInt16;
typedef unsigned __int32   AnaUInt32;
typedef unsigned __int64   AnaUInt64;

#else
// C99 standard header, may not be included with all (especially older) compilers.
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int8_t             AnaInt8;
typedef int16_t            AnaInt16;
typedef int32_t            AnaInt32;
typedef int64_t            AnaInt64;

typedef uint8_t            AnaUInt8;
typedef uint16_t           AnaUInt16;
typedef uint32_t           AnaUInt32;
typedef uint64_t           AnaUInt64;

#endif
```

The syntax error is for lines 5-12. ( starting from typedef signed __int8   AnaInt8). I'm not able to understand why it is syntax error. Any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: `__intX`is not a C++ type. If you chose something different from MSVC this may not work. It's related to the compiler, not to windows. So the `#ifdef` will not help. You may want to use the types in `<cstdint>`. Or, instead, use `#ifdef _MSC_VER` instead of WIN32. So you can be sure that this only runs with MSVC compilers.

Comment: How are `__int8`, `__int16`, `__int32`, and `__int64` defined?  Also, please include the syntax error itself.

Comment: The header file was provided by device manufacturer. I'm just tyring tp use it in my code. Eclipse just says syntax error. Doesn't give any more info. Also, I tried creating a C project in eclipse yet I get the same error. So what you are saying andreee is that I can remove this part from the header file and try?